# Prove that there exists an infinite field $F$ such that $F$ is algebraic over a finite field, and $F$ is not algebraically closed

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

> Prove that there exists a field $F$ such that
>
> 1. $F$ is infinite
> 2. $F$ is algebraic over a finite field
> 3. $F$ is not algebraically closed.

I can see that if condition (3) is removed, then the algebraic closure of the finite field is the answer. But, I can't see how to keep all the conditions in place and still make this work.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ isn't a field. Do you mean $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan yes, of course, I corrected it now.

Comment: In that case it's better to write $\mathbb{F}_q$. What do you mean by "$\mathbb{F}_q[x]$ is finite"? That's the polynomial ring which is infinite but not a field.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thanks. That analysis was wrong. I was thinking that the choice of coefficients is finite and so must be the ring (I forgot about the powers)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the quadratic closure of any finite field that does not have characteristic $2$. This is an infinite field as no finite field of characteristic other than $2$ can be quadratically closed. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/533812/what-finite-fields-are-quadratically-closed). However it is not algebraically closed as the minimal polynomial of any element over the finite field has degree $2^n$ for some $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer (+1), but I don't understand the last argument... Can you please help me in that a little bit...

Comment: @SayanDutta Any element in any algebraic extension has a minimal polynomial. In this particular extension all minimal polynomials have degree $2^n$ for some $n$. Yet there are elements in the algebraic closure whose minimal polynomial have degrees like $3$ or $10$. Thus this extension cannot be the algebraic clusure.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done using a variation of the construction of the algebraic closure of a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Namely, instead of adjoining roots of all irreducible polynomials we can fix a prime $\ell$ and adjoin only roots of irreducible polynomials of degree a power of $\ell$. Equivalently, in the algebraic closure we consider the increasing union of the subfields

$$\mathbb{F}_q \subset \mathbb{F}_{q^{\ell}} \subset \mathbb{F}_{q^{\ell^2}} \subset \dots .$$

This is the maximal $\ell$-extension of $\mathbb{F}_q$, and it is infinite and algebraic but not algebraically closed because it does not contain roots of irreducible polynomials of any other degrees except powers of $\ell$. (This is an exercise: more generally, $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$ consists of $\alpha \in \overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ whose minimal polynomials have degree dividing $n$.)

In Galois theory terms this is the subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ corresponding to the quotient map $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$, where $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \cong \text{Gal}(\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}/\mathbb{F}_q)$ is the [profinite integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer) and $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ is the $\ell$-adic integers.

Comment: I don't think $\ell$ needs to be prime. It just needs to be a natural number greater than or equal to $2$. Of course, picking it to be a prime will work.

Comment: Yes, that's right. We get the subfield of $\overline{\mathbb{F}_q}$ corresponding to the quotient map $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}} \to \mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ where $\mathbb{Z}_{\ell}$ is the product of the $p$-adic integers over all $p \mid \ell$.

Comment: You don’t need Galois theory to answer your question from this response. Just read the first two paragraphs.